# Getting HTML text for function and event

Tags: jquery, events

I have an event like this:

```
$("#page2").click(function() {
    WebOffset = "Web.Offset=1";

    var searchTerms = getSearch();
    doSearch(searchTerms);
});
```

The related ID is : `<a href="#" id="page2">2</a>`

My question is: How do I set the number 2 which is given in the HTML for the `"Web.Offset=1";` So instead of number 1 it should state:

```
"Web.Offset= HTML number of tag a";
```

How should I write this?

Comment: `WebOffset = "Web.Offset="+$("#page2").inner()` like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#page2").click(function() {
    WebOffset = "Web.Offset=" + $(this).text();

    var searchTerms = getSearch();
    doSearch(searchTerms);
});
```

Comment: if it helped you, I would suggest the OP to accept the answer !

Comment: Relax dude I couldn't accept within 10 min and then I went on with my work (What's your problem!)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#page2").click(function() {
    WebOffset = "Web.Offset="+ $(this).text();

    var searchTerms = getSearch();
    doSearch(searchTerms);
});
```